# Is there any API for fetching metadata of article using Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I want to fetch metadata of any web-page using Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger.

We can get it from this URL: [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

Example: [Open Graph Object Debugger for Google](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

It will provide all the information related to that URL. Is there any way to get this information using API(in JSON format)?

Comment: There is no API for it. But all information is available on google.com just Curl it and parse the tag yourself

Answer (score 1):

Yes, via the API URL Object described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/url/) and in even more detail [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects). Note that you can issue a POST request to this URL to force a refresh. You can even get additional data such as how many times that link was shared on Facebook!

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/?fields=og_object&id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt2015381%2F&access_token={YOUR_TOKEN}
```

I did experience inconsistencies, namely if the obejct does not exist the API will return nothing but if you query it a few seconds later it will be there. For this reason we could not rely on Facebook and simply fetched the page ourselves and parsed out the og:* tags.

It may be perfect if you don't care about misses and having to re-fetch or if you just want to programmatically clear the Facebook OG cache.

It's wise to post to it every time you create a new page to force the cache or sometimes the first person to paste the URL into Facebook won't get the link preview!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this https://urlmeta.org

Its usage is pretty simple. Just make a GET call and pass the URL to API endpoint: https://api.urlmeta.org and you are done.