# How to get title from URL in PHP from sites returning 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, url, web-crawler, cloudflare

I am trying to get the title of a few pages in PHP with this code. It works fine with almost every link except for a few, for example, with 9gag.

```
function download_page($url)
{
    $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    return $data;
}

function get_title_tag($str)
{
    $pattern = '/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/is';

    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $out))
    {
        return $out[1][0];
    }
    return false;
}

$url = "https://9gag.com/gag/avPBX3b";

$data = download_page($url);

echo $extracted_title = get_title_tag($data);
```

It echoes

> Attention Required! | Cloudflare

which seems to be protected by a Cloudflare bot verification page. But when I try to post this link on any social network, they are able get the title and all the metadata required. How is it possible?

**Edit:**

Even if I use the opengraph.io API, I get:

```
"root":{
    "error":{
        "code": 2005
        "message": "Got 403 error from server."
    }
}
```

Comment: i think because most of the website just let a limit of bots to crawl their site like google search and bing...

Comment: You should probably echo `$data` to see the full error message.

Comment: It seems 9gag tries to detect if a genuine user accessing the page and acts upon curl triying to access the data. I'd try to use Selenium to crawl it. But there might be better tools that suites your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Facebook's Graph API.

> https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/?fields=og_object&id=https://9gag.com/gag/avPBX3b

JSON Output:

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "id": "994417753967326",
      "description": "More memes, funny videos and pics on 9GAG",
      "title": "32 Places People Have Mispronounced Their Entire Life",
      "type": "article",
      "updated_time": "2020-06-12T15:54:27+0000"
   },
   "id": "https://9gag.com/gag/avPBX3b"
}
```

You can read more about it's usage [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/url).

Comment: This API gives inconsistent results, but has a better consistency rate than changing the header to `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

Comment: You can also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47070924/5073281

Answer (score 2):

just replace agent string and it should work OK, from:

```
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36';
```

to:

```
$agent = 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)';
```

I see that CloudFlare has enabled captcha verification if standard agent strings are present so this will easily bypass this. I'm puzzled with security here but that is out of scope of this question

Comment: I tried it and it's seems to be working inconsistently. Working for a few pages and not working for some other :/ Because I didn't just want to bypass CloudFlare, I wanted to bypass all the 403 Forbidden pages.